# Problems with bigfoot and lualatex in TL15

Tags: luatex, texlive, bigfoot

Consider the following MWE (for `lualatex`):

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{bigfoot}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

Up until `TL15` this wouldn't work without the `etex` package and `\reserveinserts` respectively. In `TL15` `etex` doesn't exist anymore, but unfortunately, `bigfoot` seems to make problems. I always get the following error (I actually get it two times):

```
! No room for a new \count .
\ch@ck ...\else \errmessage {No room for a new #3}
                                                  \fi 
l.621 \newinsert\FN@savebox

?
```

I guess the problem lies with `bigfoot`, but since `\reserveinserts` doesn't exist anymore, I don't know how to get around this.

**EDIT:** Here's the output of `\listfiles`:

```
article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
etoolbox.sty    2015/08/02 v2.2a e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
fontspec.sty    2015/09/24 v2.4e Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
   expl3.sty    2015/10/14 v6210 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2015/10/14 v6210 L3 programming layer 
l3unicode-data.def    2015/07/20 v5676 L3 Unicode data
l3pdfmode.def    2015/09/10 v5983 L3 Experimental driver: PDF mode
  xparse.sty    2015/10/14 v6210 L3 Experimental document command parser
luaotfload.sty    2014/08/10 v2.5-4 OpenType layout system
luatexbase.sty    2015/10/04 v1.3 luatexbase interface to LuaTeX 
ctablestack.sty    2015/10/01 v1.0 Catcode table stable support
ltluatex.tex    2015/10/02 v1.0e LuaTeX support for plain TeX (core) 
unicode-letters.def
fontspec-patches.sty    2015/09/24 v2.4e Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX

fontspec-luatex.sty    2015/09/24 v2.4e Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
 fontenc.sty
  eu2enc.def    2010/05/27 v0.1h Experimental Unicode font encodings
  eu2lmr.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
xunicode.sty    2011/09/09 v0.981 provides access to latin accents and many othe
r characters in Unicode lower plane
 eu2lmss.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0p Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
fontspec.cfg
biblatex.sty    2015/04/19 v3.0 programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex2.sty    2015/04/19 v3.0 programmable bibliographies (biber) (PK/JW/AB)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
  logreq.sty    2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
  logreq.def    2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  blx-dm.def
biblatex-dm.cfg
blx-compat.def    2015/04/19 v3.0 biblatex compatibility (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex.def    
standard.bbx    2015/04/19 v3.0 biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
 numeric.bbx    2015/04/19 v3.0 biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
 numeric.cbx    2015/04/19 v3.0 biblatex citation style (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex.cfg    
 bigfoot.sty    2015/08/30 2.1 makes footnotes work
manyfoot.sty    2005/09/11 v1.10 Many Footnote Levels Package (NCC)
nccfoots.sty    2005/02/03 v1.2 NCC Footnotes Package (NCC)
  suffix.sty    2006/07/15 1.5a Variant command support
 perpage.sty    2014/10/25 2.0 Reset/sort counters per page
 english.lbx    2015/04/19 v3.0 biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
   t3cmr.fd    2001/12/31 TIPA font definitions
supp-pdf.mkii
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
luatex-loader.sty    2010/03/09 v0.4 Lua module loader (HO)
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
```

Comment: The `etex` package is still about, but really should not be needed. Here, with an up-to-date TL15 I have no issues: can you check your file versions.

Comment: Actually, my setup should be up-to-date as well. I added the file list in the original post.

Comment: Could you also add the LaTeX2e banner line? (I have `LaTeX2e <2015/10/01> patch level 1`)

Comment: Here it says `LaTeX2e <2015/01/01> patch level 2`.

Comment: That's your problem then. (We've done our best to get the updates to work with older kernels but it's pretty tricky, particularly when third-party packages are involved.)

Comment: I was not aware of deliberately using an older kernel. I did a regular installation with `MacTex` and updated with the `TeX Live Utility`. How do I change the kernel or patch level?

Comment: as Joseph says if you put `\usepackage{etex}\reserveinserts{40}` as the first package loaded it should work in older formats that need etex package, but the code should work as posted in current latex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can occur if your kernel version is out-of-date: whilst the team have worked hard to make the changes 'transparent' there are situations where interactions between older kernels,  `ltluatex` and third-party packages may be problematic.

With an up to date TeX system the source for the newest kernel will be available. Forcing a rebuild of the format depends on your TeX system. For TeX Live (including MacTeX) the easiest way is at the Terminal to do

```
sudo fmtutil-sys --refresh
```

For MiKTeX, from the MiKTeX Maintenance entry on the Start Menu, choose Settings then Update Formats.

---

Note that the `etex` package is still available so for older formats the approach

```
\RequirePackage{etex}
\reserveinserts{40}
...
```

will work.

Comment: This didn't change anything. Adding `\RequirePackage[latest]{latexrelease}` did the trick though.

Comment: @Simifilm In that case something is not up-to-date: the latest kernel release is `2015/10/01 PL 1` so unless you get that as a banner something is wrong.

Comment: I now completely deleted MacTeX and did a re-install – no success. I'm still at patch level 2. No idea what's going on here.

Comment: @Simifilm Depending on how you built your formats the files might be in `~/ Library/texlive/2015/texmf-var/`: try deleting that directory.

Comment: @Simifilm Do you perhaps have a 'local' install of LaTeX? What does `kpsewhich latex.ltx` report, and if you look at that file what is the file version there?

Comment: Finally! Deleting `~/ Library/texlive/2015/texmf-var/` did the trick. Thanks a lot.